# Need to Insert Encapsulated XML Element With MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, xml, simplexml

- I'm parsing an xml string and trying to insert an encapsulated element into a MySQL database
- I'm using the query below. The *ID* value inserts correctly, but the *first_name* value does not
- Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

  ```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO db_table (id, first_name) VALUES ('$person->id', '$person->{\'first-name\'} )");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape properly:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO db_table (id, first_name) VALUES ('{$person->id}', '" . $person-{'first-name'} . "')");
```

You shouldn't really use mysql_ functions anymore, though